# find out boot sequence on linux OS

Tags: linux, boot

When a linux OS is booting there is a boot sequence. How can I find this boot sequence?

Specific:
I have an AR.Drone, powered by 1 GHz A8 CPU, 1 GB RAM and linux OS. I want to tweak some things but first I have to figure out the boot sequence. The drones config is done by *.sh scripts and I have a telnet access. So I can change a lot of things.

Could you help me finding the boot order? Which script is executed first?

(There is no rc.local)

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for my first drone to arrive - I just won one :) So this is not from personal knowledge I'm afraid.

However, the following is from [a blog](http://embedded-software.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/ar-drones-boot-sequence.html) I found:

> #### A.R. Drone's boot sequence
>
> In order to be able to flash a
>   custom kernel to A.R. Drone, it is necessary to understand it's boot
>   sequence:
>
> - After reset, the program counter starts at the beginning P6 internal ROM. In this internal ROM, some kind of pre-bootloader exists
>     that evaluates external pins and selects the corresponding boot mode
>     (e.g. boot over USB, NAND, IIC, UART, ... ). Depending on the selected
>     mode, the peripherals are set-up and it is tried to boot over this
>     peripheral.
> - Boot over NAND: The pre-bootloader starts the memory controller, copies the bootloader from NAND to internal RAM and sets
>     the program counter to the address in internal RAM which basically
>     starts the bootloader.
> - Boot over USB: The pre-bootloader listens to USB and waits for the "Hello P6" command. If received, it replies and awaits an
>     image (the usb_bootloader.bin). The received data is copied to
>     internal RAM and the program counter is changed to the internal RAM
>     address wich in effect starts the bootloader.
> - Depending on the started bootloader, either the UBI partitions are "mounted" and the kernel image is read or the bootloader waits
>     until the kernel image is sent over USB.
> - If the installer.plf (which is basically a kernel image) is booted over USB, the "init" command of this image awaits the actual
>     firmware (ardrone_update.plf) over USB and installs the content to
>     NAND.

Answer (score 0):

Booting requires a kernel and a boot disk (or the image of one in ROM/RAM/Flash), these might be provided by the means of the boot loader e.g. `grub`
What happens next depends on how it all was set up.

How a "standard Linux" starts is described [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/boot.7.html).

I think you might have better success in asking questions here:
https://devzone.parrot.com/

**---**
*"This website is dedicated to the applications developers for Parrot ASTEROID range.*

*As Parrot ASTEROID devices are **powered by Android**, this Developers Zone points out similarities and differences between Android and ASTEROID platforms.*

*For reading the development and distribution guides (tutorials and code samples), getting help and discussing about the ASTEROID project, please Sign up, Log in and read wiki pages or use the forum"*